# Nexus 4 with no signal (sleep mode)

Tags: nexus-4, standby

I have a problem with my sister's Nexus4.
When I try to call her I have the reply that the phone is off while if I call the other phone (HTC Legend with the same operator) I can talk regularly.

It happened both at home or outside.

It is not a operator problem because I change the operator twice and with the same operator in the same places I can phone with no problem.

The strange is that when a try to call N4 I am not able to start the call and after that the N4 receive a sms with the "lost call" and return it on-line.

it seems it falls in a sleep mode when the creen is off

Comment: What's your question? It just sounds like you have a faulty phone.

Comment: How can i solve it? I think all hardware are the same, so I am not a solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the phone with a landline. If the problem persists try a factory reset, if that don't fix the problem I'm afraid you have a hardware issue.